# Determine if a place falls in within a route using google maps api

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am writing a backend (MongoDB,express, NodeJs) which takes latitude and longitude from the android app. I have to determine is a certain place is within a particular route.

assume there is a route

```
A --> B
```

now there is a place called C, which I want to find out if it lies between A and B.

```
A--> C --> B
```

I also want to make sure that the total distance travelled in the case of A-->C-->B is within a tolerable distance compared to the distance between `A-->B`

As i was trying to solve this problem I came across two solutions

1. Use of isLocationOnEdge() by geometry library
2. Use of awesome library called routeBoxer

But unfortunately I am unable to use either of them as they both are libraries and not npm modules. Is there a way to use them or is there any other solution available?

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to create radius circles along each point in the polyline and check your location to see if it's within the bounds of any of those circles.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the distance you are trying to measure is strictly linear, there is a function included in the geometry library of Google Maps JavaScript API that is called `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`. It accepts two `LatLng`s as arguments.

```
var originalDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a, b)
var newDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a, c) + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(c, b)
var difference = newDist - originalDist
```

If you are trying to figure out how far `C` is from any of the points making up the polyline of `A-->B`, you can take an iterative approach:

```
min(
  polyline.map(
    function(pt){
      return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, c)
    }
  )
)
```

This is far more efficient than drawing circles, since it does not involve the initialization of an object.

A substitute for `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` is the [Haversine Formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (conveniently written in JavaScript).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am already using Haversine formula to calculate distance between two locations which are pretty near, so that we can assume they are strictly linear. But I am more looking at calculating the distance travelled than the displacement. And also i am using MEAN stack, so im facing problem in referring to any of the JS libraries which are not available as npm modules :(